# Quick tabs: Passing current nid to a view

Tags: views, blocks

I have a content type called products. The url is products/[node:title], i.e. /products/pear, products/banana, etc.

On the node page itself many of the fields of that node are hidden, because I want them displayed in tabs, along with content from associated nodes (via Entity References). So I am using Quicktabs and views to display this content. However, I can't work out how to pass the NID to a view if it doesn't appear in the URL. Since I just want to pass the NID of the page I am on, this seems like it should be a simple issue, but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've worked it out. The URL that QuickTabs references is the **System** URL, so the NID is there and can be referenced just by %1.

I knew there would be a simple answer! Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use contextual filters on your view.

1. Under view settings -> Advanced -> contextual filters -> Add
   'Content: Nid'
2. Under 'When the filter value is not available' -> provide default
   value -> Content ID from URL

Then save the filter / view and it should be set up to pull the nid from whatever page it is displayed on.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Actually that wasn't the issue I was having, but I worked it out literally when you posted. I will post the answer below. Thanks again.